# What files should be contained in a python sdist?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm asking what the standard practice is for generating an `sdist`. Should the `sdist` effectively contain most or all of the files in the repository? Or should the `sdist` contain only the set of files that is needed to build an archive such as `whl` or `egg`?

The question has arisen at the [Trac project](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/12833#comment:34). Let me give some concrete examples about files I'm considering. Should we include?:

- Developer documentation in RST format (these files are not included in the `whl` we distribute)
- Repository artifacts like `.gitignore`
- Python scripts in `contrib` that are not included in the egg or whl, but are generally useful
- The compiled translation catalogs (`mo` files) that are artifacts of the build and not stored in the repository

Answer (score 2):

Source distributions are used to install packages. `pip` downloads an sdist, unpacks it and runs

```
python setup.py install
```

Hence sdist must contains everything required to build and install the package. Everything else — up to the packagers. sdist could contain additional files like docs, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The Source Distribution (`sdist`) is a distribution format used to installing libraries from source files.

Quoting the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/):

> A distribution format (usually generated using `python setup.py sdist`) that provides metadata and the essential source files needed for installing by a tool like `pip`, or for generating a Built Distribution.

Nowadays, we use Version control system like Git, Subversion or Mercurial to store the source of the library. So, the `sdist` format mainly contains what the VCS contains.

Contrary to the Wheel format which contains everything needed to "run" the library/application. For instance, Wheels don't contain unit test, documentation, etc.